# Routing error on dynamic select rails 4 and ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

Been working this issue and can't figure it out.

Trying to make a dynamic select to pick a city based on a state. This is for a devise user registration page, which I think is only adding to the routing error.

Ajax Code: (assets/javascripts/registration.js.coffee)

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#user_state_id', (evt) ->
  $.ajax '/registrations/update_cities',
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'script'
    data: {
      state_id: $("#user_state_id option:selected").val()
    }
    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
      console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
      console.log("Dynamic state select OK!")
```

Controller (registrations_controller.rb)

```
def edit
  @states = State.all
  @cities = Cities.where("state_id = ?", State.first.id)
end

def update_cities
  @cities = Cities.where("state_id = ?", params[:state_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Update JS: (views/devise/registrations/update_cities.js.coffee)

```
$("#user_city_id").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @cities)) %>")
```

Shared Partial (views/shared/_city.html.erb)

```
<option value="<%= city.id %>"><%= city.name.titleize %></option>
```

Routes (for reference)

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'} do
  get 'registrations/update_cities', as: 'update_cities'
end
```

Error (in logs)

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/registrations/update_cities"):
```

`rake routes` output

```
            states GET    /states(.:format)              states#index
                     POST   /states(.:format)              states#create
           new_state GET    /states/new(.:format)          states#new
          edit_state GET    /states/:id/edit(.:format)     states#edit
               state GET    /states/:id(.:format)          states#show
                     PATCH  /states/:id(.:format)          states#update
                     PUT    /states/:id(.:format)          states#update
                     DELETE /states/:id(.:format)          states#destroy
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               registrations#create
 new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          registrations#edit
                     PATCH  /users(.:format)               registrations#update
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)               registrations#destroy
 dashboards_list_zip GET    /dashboards/list_zip(.:format) dashboards#list_zip
  authenticated_root GET    /                              dashboards#index
                root GET    /                              devise/sessions#new
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm trying to implement something like what was done at: [Kernal Garden](https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/); with modifications for Devise and state/city levels.

Comment: Can you also show the results of `rake routes`?

Comment: added. noted that the update_cities based on new scoping isn't there anymore

Comment: Odd.  I don't see update_cites in the `rake routes` output.  Did it get clipped, or is it not creating a route?

Comment: not creating a route sadly.

Comment: Looks like the routing error is fixed for the ajax call, but now throws `Started GET "/registrations/update_cities?state_id=39&_=1463454058839" for ::1 at 2016-05-16 23:03:58 -0400
Processing by RegistrationsController#update_cities as JS
  Parameters: {"state_id"=>"39", "_"=>"1463454058839"}
[Devise] Could not find devise mapping for path "/registrations/update_cities?state_id=39&_=1463454058839".`

Comment: fixed this error by changing route to `:user'

Comment: So does that mean that it's working for you?

Comment: Close. Really appreciate your help. Now getting a `ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial` for @cities. Going to hang it up for the night and continue troubleshooting tomorrow. Thanks again Michael.

Comment: No worries.  I can look at it in the meantime and if I have any thoughts, I'll update my answer to include them.  Have a great night!

Comment: I tried one more thing and it looks like I got it working. Now just need to mess around as the variable isn't saving. Need to dig into the permit area a bit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work this way: 
registration.js.coffee:

```
$ ->
$(document).on 'change', '#user_state_id', (evt) ->
 $.ajax '/registrations/update_cities',
  type: 'GET'
  dataType: 'script'
  data: {
    state_id: $("#user_state_id option:selected").val()
  }
  error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
    console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
  success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    console.log("Dynamic state select OK!")
```

registrations controller:

```
def edit
 @states = State.all
 if current_user.state_id.nil?
  @cities = City.where("state_id = ?", State.first.id)
 else
  @cities = City.where("state_id = ?", current_user.state_id) 
 end
end

def update_cities
 @cities = City.where("state_id = ?", params[:state_id])
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js
 end
end
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `registration.js.coffee` coffeescript isn't rendered, so it won't be able to use the route helper for `update_cities`.  Instead, it's treating the path as relative to your current path, so it becomes `/users/update_cities` instead.

Change this line:

```
$.ajax 'update_cities',
```

to this:

```
$.ajax '/registrations/update_cities',
```

Let's try this route:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'} do
end

get '/users/update_cities', to: :registrations, as: 'update_cities'
```

It may require you to put the url back to what you had it before, but this should give you a route for `update_cities`

Comment: That solved my initial routing error but getting a new routing error that says I'm not wrapping the route inside the `devise_for` scope block. If I move it into the block the old routing error comes back now saying `(No route matches [GET] "/registrations/update_cities")`

Comment: Updating the question above for easy reading (based on Michael's initial answer.

Comment: I added a route change to my answer.  Want to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Didn't solve the question, but I did upvote it. I'll post the functional solution once it allows me to.